# Is this Inner Join Statement Correct?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

newlist - 20,000 data

recordlist - 200,000 data

I want to display all the match record from newlist to recordlist

it must be match in FIRSTNAME,MIDDLENAME,LASTNAME

```
SELECT new.FIRSTNAME,new.MIDDLENAME,new.LASTNAME 
FROM newlist as new 
INNER JOIN recordlist as bgc ON new.FIRSTNAME = bgc.FIRSTNAME 
AND new.MIDDLENAME = bgc.MIDDLENAME AND new.LASTNAME = bgc.LASTNAME";
```

is this query correct? to display all the matches?

Comment: The query is correct, but your logic is going to match anything with same name or same middlename or same lastname. For example "John Snow" would be matched with "John Rain" because firstname is same. Depending on data this could result in multiplication of matches. To change this, you shold change your "OR" to "AND".

Comment: why not try and see if it returns the expected result

Comment: the problem is it takes time to load due to recordlist has 200,000 records.

Comment: Be aware of reserved keywords in MySql. As you use 'new' as a table name. NEW is a reserved word in (my)Sql.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: `FROM newlist AS new`, isn't there something wrong with the `AS`? I see no `AS` in the documentation for the `SELECT` syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

You indexed the three columns I assume? If not do so :)

When they are already indexed:

With multiple OR's, sometimes its better to split the query and join the result sets with a Union. This for using the index.

```
SELECT new.FIRSTNAME,new.MIDDLENAME,new.LASTNAME 
FROM newlist as new 
INNER JOIN recordlist as bgc ON new.FIRSTNAME = bgc.FIRSTNAME 
UNION
SELECT new.FIRSTNAME,new.MIDDLENAME,new.LASTNAME 
FROM newlist as new 
INNER JOIN recordlist as bgc ON new.MIDDLENAME = bgc.MIDDLENAME 
UNION
SELECT new.FIRSTNAME,new.MIDDLENAME,new.LASTNAME 
FROM newlist as new 
INNER JOIN recordlist as bgc ON new.LASTNAME = bgc.LASTNAME"
```

Comment: Hm I'm pretty sure indexing a first name is a terrible idea since two people can definetly have the same first name.

Comment: Indexing does not mean it has to be a UNIQUE index. Example: When you look for John Doe his telephone number, you start looking by all names starting with a 'D' right? That's using an index.

Comment: Oh man you're right, damn I have work to do with my new tables!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention anything about indexes. I'm assuming you are not using them. With a 200.000-long table you basically have to.

Adding the indexes may take a while, but you only need to do it once per table. And if it's done at table creation, it takes < 10ms.

To add the indexes:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `new` ADD INDEX (FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, LASTNAME);
ALTER TABLE `bcg` ADD INDEX (FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, LASTNAME);
```

Then you can use the following query to do your thing:

```sql
SELECT
  `new`.FIRSTNAME,
  `new`.MIDDLENAME,
  `new`.LASTNAME 
FROM newlist `new`
  INNER JOIN recordlist `bgc`
    ON `new`.FIRSTNAME = `bgc`.FIRSTNAME 
      AND `new`.MIDDLENAME = `bgc`.MIDDLENAME
      AND `new`.LASTNAME = `bgc`.LASTNAME";
```

Comment: @VigneshKumar hmm, could you elaborate a little bit here?

Comment: @kimdecastro could you post a comparison of the execution time of the answers given in that post? I'm curious about which one is the fastest.

Comment: wait I got an error execution time out. will try both solution now I updated to 300 exectime.

Comment: @kimdecastro you must find a way to add indexes in your tables, see my last edit idea for that.

Comment: @kimdecastro edited again with all the code you need to add the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

**Indexes 3 Columns** will display the result very fast.

it takes 5 seconds to display the result.

```
SELECT new.FIRSTNAME,new.MIDDLENAME,new.LASTNAME 
FROM newlist as new 
INNER JOIN recordlist as bgc ON new.FIRSTNAME = bgc.FIRSTNAME 
AND new.MIDDLENAME = bgc.MIDDLENAME AND new.LASTNAME = bgc.LASTNAME";
```